# Selectric not working when added dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-selectric

I used the following code to clone the form elements and append to the target in button click.

```
   $('#addChild').on('click', function () {
                var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, 
                newNum  = new Number(num + 1),      
                newElem = $('#entry' + num).clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); 

             if (newNum == 4) { 
                    alert("Sorry, You can add upto 3 childrens only");
                    return false; 
             } 

            newElem.find('.heading-reference').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_reference').html('Child #' + newNum);

            // Title - select
            newElem.find('.fnameLabel').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_title');
            newElem.find('.fName').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_fName').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_fName').val('');

            // First name - text
            newElem.find('.surLabel').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_sName');
            newElem.find('.sName').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_sName').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_sName').val('');

            // Last name - text
            newElem.find('.genderLabel').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_gender');
            newElem.find('.genderSelect').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_gender').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_gender');


            // Color - checkbox
            newElem.find('.dobLab').attr('for', 'ID' + newNum + '_dobLab');
            newElem.find('.dob').attr('id', 'ID' + newNum + '_dob').attr('name', 'ID' + newNum + '_dob');

            $('#entry' + num).after(newElem);
            $('#ID' + newNum + '_title').focus();


           $('#btnDel').attr('disabled', false);

     });
```

But the problem is, after cloning selectric select box is not working for cloned items. I dont know where i missed. Any help will be much appreciated.

Please check the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/vandanasrivastava/ug1ders7/

Comment: You want to reset it to default for cloning in the next row? right?

Comment: no .. after cloning the selectric is not working for cloned items. When i click on selectric select box of cloned items , its not opening .... see the fiddle for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have initialized *selectric* before `.clone()`, so that the whole element (already modified by *selectric* plugin) is cloned.

You should clone the element before initializing the plugin.

```
// clone it before .selectric():
var newEl = $('#entry1').clone();
// initialize plugin:
$(".basic").selectric();
$('#addChild').on('click', function () {

    var num     = $('.clonedInput').length, 
        newNum  = new Number(num + 1),
        // use cloned object without the data appended by selectric:      
        newElem = newEl.clone().attr('id', 'entry' + newNum).fadeIn('slow'); 

    // ...

    // Then initialize the plugin for the new ".basic" elements:
    $(newElem).appendTo('.allCatsContainer').find(".basic").selectric();

});
```

[<kbd>**JSFiddle demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/jen8x1ry/)

---

Another thing is that all cloned `<select>` elements have the same ids': (`#gender`, `#day`, `#month`, `#year`)
Modify these id's too or don't use them if you don't need.

Answer (score 2):

This is an indirect method , you can remove the selectric item from cloned object then reset the select option by default values before append to div , then initialize selectric in appended select box.

```
  var clone =  $('.clonedInput').clone();//Clone the input
  clone.find(".clonedInput").val(''); // Clear the selected value

  //Trigger the action here 
  var default_html = clone.find(".clonedInput").parent('div').html();//will take the html content of your select box
  //clonedInputParentDiv is the name of your clonedInput parents div
  clone.find('.clonedInputParentDiv').children('.selectric-wrapper').remove();//Removing all selectric variables from clone
  clone.find('.clonedInputParentDiv').append(title); // Append to clone as normal selectbox


  clone.find(".clonedInput").selectric();// Initialize the selectric in new appended selectbox
  clone.insertAfter('.clonedInput:last');
```